# For a non-square matrix $X$, what conditions must be satisfied so that $X^t\cdot X$ results in the identity matix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $X$ is an $N\times M$ real valued matrix  (with $N < M$), the product of its transpose with itself ($X^t\cdot X$) results in a square $M\times M$ matrix.

Is there some simple property that $X$ has to obey so the the product ($X^t\cdot X$) is the identity matrix?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Rectangular_matrices

Comment: It can't happen.  Rank of $X^T X$ is at most the rank of $X$, so at most N.  That's less than M.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSaltz! That is indeed interesting.

Comment: I would say that the simple property you want is orthogonality, which is defined as $X^TX=I$. But as @hardmath says, this is impossible if $N<M$.

Comment: @hardmath Ah yes, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @mathhead: Maybe you meant to flip the product the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ can be obtained by removing columns from a square orthogonal matrix, then $X^TX=I$. (Note that this imposes the condition $N\geq M$.)

Proof: Let $X_{ij}=A_{ik_j}$, where $1\leq k_0<k_1<\dots<k_M\leq N$ selects the columns from the square matrix $A$ satisfying $A^TA=I$. In full sum form,

$$\begin{align}
A^TA=I\Rightarrow\sum_aA_{ai}A_{aj}&=\delta_{ij} \\
\sum_aX_{ai}X_{aj}=\sum_aA_{ak_i}A_{ak_j}&=\delta_{k_ik_j}=\delta_{ij}\Rightarrow X^TX=I, \\
\end{align}$$

where $\delta_{k_ik_j}=\delta_{ij}$ because $k_i=k_j$ iff $i=j$.

Comment: Thanks @mario-carneiro. Would upvote as well but i don't have enough reputation yet.